# Refactor some calls on each Zf2 controller action

Tags: php, architecture, zend-framework2, refactoring

I need to do a custom `isGranted` method (not using Rbac or acl module from community). So I have a service which provides the functionality. But this code:

```
if (!$this->userService->isGrantedCustom($this->session->offsetGet('cod_lvl'), 'ZF_INV_HOM')) {
    throw new \Exception("you_are_not_allowed", 1);
}
```

...is duplicated in each controller and each action I have. Parameters are changing of course depends on the permission (`'ZF_INV_HOM'`, `'ZF_TODO_DELETE'` ...).

I think it's not a bad idea to do this code before the controller is called, but I can't figure what is the best solution (best architecture), and how to pass those parameters to it (I thought about annotation on controllers but how to handle this ?).

The point is, if I have to modify this code I can't imagine to do that hundreds of times, for each controllers, each action I have I need to have this code in one place.

Comment: where do you get *ZF_INV_HOM* param? You should connect it to event manager.

Comment: Each controller has a permission name for granted access to it, its defined  in action controller itself, and there is a match with permission of my users (custom RBAC) in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to pollute your Module with all this code you can also make a listener class and attach only the listener in your bootstrap method:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Listener;

use Application\Service\UserService;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\SharedListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;

class IsAllowedListener implements SharedListenerAggregateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthenticationServiceInterface
     */
    protected $authService;

    /**
     * @var UserService
     */
    protected $userService;

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler[]
     */
    protected $sharedListeners = array();

    /**
     * @param SharedEventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function attachShared(SharedEventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $this->sharedListeners[] = $events->attach(AbstractActionController::class, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'isAllowed'), 1000);
    }

    public function __construct(AuthenticationServiceInterface $authService, UserService $userService ){
        $this->authService = $authService;
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    /**
     * @param MvcEvent $event
     */
    protected function isAllowed(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $authService = $this->getAuthService();
        $identity = $authService->getIdentity();

        $userService = $this->getUserService();

        if($userService->isGrantedCustom()){
            // User is granted we can return
            return;
        }

        // Return not allowed response
    }

    /**
     * @return AuthenticationServiceInterface
     */
    public function getAuthService()
    {
        return $this->authService;
    }

    /**
     * @param AuthenticationServiceInterface $authService
     */
    public function setAuthService(AuthenticationServiceInterface $authService)
    {
        $this->authService = $authService;
    }

    /**
     * @return UserService
     */
    public function getUserService()
    {
        return $this->userService;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserService $userService
     */
    public function setUserService(AuthenticationServiceInterface $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }
}
```

You need to setup a factory to inject your dependencies:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Listener;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

/**
 * Factory for creating the IsAllowedListener
 */
class IsAllowedListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create the IsAllowedListener
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return RenderLinksListener
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $authService = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
        $userService = $serviceLocator->get('Application\Service\UserService');
        return new IsAllowedListener($authService, $userService );
    }
}
```

And register all this in config:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Listener\IsAllowedListener' => 'Application\Listener\IsAllowedListenerFactory'
    )
)
```

And then in bootstrap:

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
{
    $application    = $event->getTarget();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $eventManager   = $application->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    $isAllowedListener = $serviceManager->get('Application\Listener\IsAllowedListener')
    $sharedEventManager->attachAggregate($isAllowedListener);
}
```

Instead of using `AbstractActionController::class`, you could also make a specific class, so you will only listen to instances of that class.

So for example `AbstractIsAllowedActionController::class` or something like that.

Comment: +1 *This* is the best way to do this; you encapsulate the listeners logic and use a service factory for its dependencies.

Comment: You right, according to your comment, you cover all my interrogations. Thanks :) @AlexP thanks too

Answer (score 2):

By attaching an event listener to the SharedEventManager you can target all controllers and have the authorization check in just one place.

In this case the target is `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` which means any controller extending it will execute the listener. The high priority of this listener will mean that it is executed prior to the target controller action, giving you the chance to handle any requests that have not been authorized.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application  = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

    $eventManager->attach(
        \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController::class, // Identity of the target controller
        MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
        [$this, 'isAllowed'],
        1000  // high priority
    );
}
```

In each controller there would need to be some way that you can determine which 'resource' is being accessed.

As an example it could implement this interface

```
interface ResourceInterface
{
    // Return a unique key representing the resource
    public function getResourceId();
}
```

The listener could then look like this.

```
public function isAllowed(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    // We need the 'current' user identity
    $authService = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
    $identity = $authService->getIdentity();

    // The service that performs the authorization
    $userService = $serviceManager->get('MyModule\Service\UserService');

    // The target controller is itself a resource (the thing we want to access)
    // in this example it returns an resource id so we know what we want to access
    // but you could also get this 'id' from the request or config etc
    $controller = $event->getTarget();

    if ($controller instanceof ResourceInterface) {
        $resourceName = $controller->getResourceId();

        // Test the authorization, is UserX allowed resource ID Y
        if (empty($resourceName) || $userService->isGrantedCustom($identity, $resourceName)) {
            // early exit for success
            return;
        } else {
           // Denied; perhaps trigger a new custom event or return a response
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have a doubt on high priority, are your sure that 1000 is higher than -1000 ? i can't make myself clear about this link http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html and priority on listeners

Comment: Shouldnt be in *isAllowed(MvcEvent $event)* `if ($event->getTarget() instanceof ResourceInterface) {/*...*/}`

Comment: @venca You are correct, you would need to check. I've added it.

Comment: @Hooli Straight from [the documentation **Assigning Priority to Listeners**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html): *The third argument to attach() is a priority value. The higher this number, the earlier that listener will execute; the lower it is, the later it executes. The value defaults to 1, and values will trigger in the order registered within a given priority.*